# Stored procedure in MySQL replace zero value with an space empty

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure on database MySql version 8.0.17

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP`(IN tun CHAR(100), 
tmonth int(2), 
tparag LONGTEXT, 
tid int(11))
BEGIN

declare 2tun char(100);
declare 2tmonth int(2);
declare 2tyear int(4);
DECLARE 2tparag LONGTEXT;
DECLARE 2tid INT(11);

SET 2tun = tun;
SET 2tmonth = tmonth;
SET 2tyear = YEAR(CURDATE());
SET 2tparag = tparag;
SET 2tid = tid;

SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE t_contents_', 2tun, '_', 2tmonth, '_', 2tyear, ' 
                 SET contents = \'',2tparag,'\'
                 WHERE sID = \'',2tid,'\';');
                                 
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;                             

END
```

This code working correctly.

But if trying with this other version of SP where I replace the new lines `('\r' OR '\n' OR '\r\n')` present on `2tparag` variable value with an space

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP`(IN tun CHAR(100), 
tmonth int(2), 
tparag LONGTEXT, 
tid int(11))
BEGIN

declare 2tun char(100);
declare 2tmonth int(2);
declare 2tyear int(4);
DECLARE 2tparag LONGTEXT;
DECLARE 2tid INT(11);

SET 2tun = tun;
SET 2tmonth = tmonth;
SET 2tyear = YEAR(CURDATE());
SET 2tparag = tparag;
SET 2tid = tid;

SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE t_contents_', 2tun, '_', 2tmonth, '_', 2tyear, ' 
                 SET contents = \'',REPLACE(2tparag,'\r' OR '\n' OR '\r\n', ' '),'\' 
                 WHERE sID = \'',2tid,'\';');
                                 
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                                 
END
```

when I write `2021` on `2tparag` variable on the database the field it update with `2 21` value...

how to do resolve this?

**Example**

The start string is

```
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum
```

Updating this string with adding current year

```
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum 2021
```

On the database is stored

```
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum 2 21
```

Comment: Please add an example of the call statement which is not producing the desired result.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for reply. pls see **example** in the qst

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the replace function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace that or can be used and I am surprised that mysql does not syntax error-Do you have a reference for this syntax?

Comment: @P.Salmon https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx/

Comment: The syntax in the link is REPLACE(str,old_string,new_string); - no ORs in sight..nevertheless replace with OR seems to work as an undocumented (and therefore dubious) feature. I would stick to the documented syntax and use  replace(replace(REPLACE(2tparag,'\r',' '),'\n', ' '),'\r\n', ' ') - doesn't solve your issue I know.

Comment: @P.Salmon thank you solved using `contents = \'',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(2tparag,'\n', ' '),'\r', ' '),'\r\n', ' '),'\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your query

Your `REPALCE` will not work that way as you intended, Mysql will onöly replace **one** occurance of the charateers , so only pmne of `\n`, `\r`or `\n\r`

To repaölce all ocurances you nbeed to use

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('test\na\rb','\r' , ' '),'\n' , ' '),'\r\n', ' ')
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t_contents_123_2_2021(sID int, contents LONGTEXT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t_contents_123_2_2021 VALUEs(1,'test')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `SP`(IN tun CHAR(100), 
> tmonth int(2), 
> tparag LONGTEXT, 
> tid int(11))
> BEGIN
>
> declare 2tun char(100);
> declare 2tmonth int(2);
> declare 2tyear int(4);
> DECLARE 2tparag LONGTEXT;
> DECLARE 2tid INT(11);
>
> SET 2tun = tun;
> SET 2tmonth = tmonth;
> SET 2tyear = YEAR(CURDATE());
> SET 2tparag = tparag;
> SET 2tid = tid;
>
> SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE t_contents_', 2tun, '_', 2tmonth, '_', 2tyear, ' 
>                  SET contents = \'',REPLACE(2tparag,'\r' OR '\n' OR '\r\n', ' '),'\' 
>                  WHERE sID = \'',2tid,'\';');
>                                  
> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>  
> END
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CALL SP ('123','02', 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum',1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t_contents_123_2_2021
> ```
>
> ```
> sID | contents                                  
> --: | :-----------------------------------------
>   1 | Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2663801dff43e4a4db89bbe251df7f6f)*